# Proof that a Hermitian matrix $A=cI$

Tags: linear-algebra

The problems asks that one prove if the eigenvalues of a Hermitian or skew-Hermitian matrix $A$ are all equal to $c$, then $A=cI$.

I came up with a proof but I'm not sure it's logically valid, and even if it is, probably not the best way of tackling the problem. I was wondering if someone could check the validity of this proof and explain if there are errors in reasoning, and provide a better proof if possible.

**Thm A**: Assume $\dim V = n$ and let $T: V\rightarrow V$ be Hermitian or skew-Hermitian. Then there exist n eigenvectors that form an orthonormal basis for $V$. The matrix of $T$ relative to this basis is the diagonal matrix of the eigenvalues $\lambda_k$, where $\lambda_k$ is the eigenvalue associated with the kth eigenvector in the basis.

Let $T$ be the linear transformation represented by the matrix $A$ for the basis $E= (e_1,e_2,...,e_k)$. We know that there is a diagonal matrix $cI$ for $T$ with an orthonormal basis formed from the eigenvectors of $c$; let this basis be $U = (u_1,u_2,...,u_k)$ from Thm A.

Then we have $e_j = \sum_{i=1}^k a_iu_i$ for $j=1,2,...,k$. Then $T(e_j) = \sum_{i=1}^k a_iT(u_i) = \sum_{i=1}^k a_icu_i$, from the definition of $T$. Then $T(e_j) = c\sum_{i=1}^k a_iu_i = ce_j$. But then $e_j$ is an eigenvector of the transformation $T$ so by Thm A, $A=cI$.

Comment: Just think about canonical form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the proof is valid though (slightly) convoluted. After using your Thm A, there is no need to use the standard basis. You can directly show that  $T(x) = cx$ for all $x$  by expanding $x$ in terms of your eigenvector basis $u_k$.

Answer (score 4):

I see no issue, but you could simply note that by the theorem, $A=UcIU^{-1}$ and since scalar matrices commute with all other matrices, $UcIU^{-1}=cI$.